# CSS for sharepoint site settings

Tags: css, sharepoint

I've got a master page that loads in a custom css file. This works fine for the published pages that the end user sees. however, the css also affects the site settings pages which look terrible. Is there a way to only provide a custom css file for the published pages?

Comment: Did you change the System Master Page in Site Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers @Neps. There was a different master page for system, but I found out I was using the alternate CSS which was applying the style sheet to both. so I removed that and put the link code directly into the master page.